# Unity Facebook SDK couldn't connect to host

Tags: facebook-unity-sdk

Hi there I am working on a project that implements Parse along with Facebook SDK. Everything was fine until a few days ago. Since than FB skd simply wont connect to the servers. I am getting the following errors in the editor :

Most common is this one I get it 7 out of 10 attempts:

```
    couldn't connect to hostUnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
```

FbDebug:Error(String) c__Iterator1:MoveNext() (at Assets/Facebook/Scripts/FB.cs:368)

another one is this  (1/10)

```
Could not find the Facebook Skin: couldn't connect to host
UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
FbDebug:Error(String)
<Start>c__Iterator4:MoveNext() (at Assets/Facebook/Scripts/EditorFacebookAccessToken.cs:31)
```

1 time of 10 it initializes ok but on login screen returns an error that cannot load the canvas (the login screen is transparent, no fb colors). And finally 1 out of 10 times it passes the login and everything works.

I have checked both my networks, that except this thing appear to work correctly and same effect. Now, If I connect to my phone 3g via USB tethering all works fine. So its apparently my networks. Both networks are high speed (50MBit I think) and I am connected via cable. I have tried restarting routers, and flushing dns but still the same.

Now the question is, why can this be happening ? How can I try to find a workaround ? 
Best Regards

Of course the numbers are approximate, it throws these errors randomly.

Comment: what version of the SDK are you using? 6.0 is in Beta if you want to give it a try (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/downloads - go down to the beta section). Please feel free to email any information to unity_sdk@fb.com, if you have a live app we can test that would be great. Sorry for the inconvenience!

Comment: SDK is fine (as i wrote in my post), the problem was with my ISP, we contacted them tell them to fix it, and now the problem is gone !